# org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'ordersServiceImpl'

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, javabeans

I'm a new enthusiast for programming in Java SpringBoot and I'd being developing some projects, like this one I'll show you next.
I appreciate if you can help me, cause this got me a heavy headache. I tried to create a Query using a parameter/property from entity Orders to connect later to a view with Thymeleaf expressions, but somehow it failed the connection before.

So, this is the error message output:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'ordersServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'ordersDAO'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ordersDAO' defined in cl.duoc.proyectoInventario.dao.OrdersDAO defined in @EnableJdbcRepositories declared on JdbcRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJdbcRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.UnsupportedFragmentException: Repository cl.duoc.proyectoInventario.dao.OrdersDAO implements org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryByExampleExecutor but JdbcRepositoryFactory does not support Query by Example!
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ordersDAO' defined in cl.duoc.proyectoInventario.dao.OrdersDAO defined in @EnableJdbcRepositories declared on JdbcRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJdbcRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.UnsupportedFragmentException: Repository cl.duoc.proyectoInventario.dao.OrdersDAO implements org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryByExampleExecutor but JdbcRepositoryFactory does not support Query by Example!
> Caused by: org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.UnsupportedFragmentException: Repository cl.duoc.proyectoInventario.dao.OrdersDAO implements org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryByExampleExecutor but JdbcRepositoryFactory does not support Query by Example!

PS: I apologize for my english

**Domain**

```
package com.example.proyectoInventario.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(value="orders")
public class Orders implements Serializable {
    @Id // id 
    private Integer orderNumber;
    
    @Column
    private String orderDate;
    
    @Column
    private String requiredDate;
    
    @Column
    private String shippedDate;
    
    @Column
    private String status;
    
    @Column
    private String comments;
 
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="CustomerNumber")
    private Customers customer;
}
```

**Repository / DAO**

```
package com.example.proyectoInventario.dao;

import com.example.proyectoInventario.domain.Orders;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface OrdersDAO extends JpaRepository<Orders,Integer>{
    
    @Query("SELECT o FROM orders o WHERE o.status= :status")
    List<Orders> findByStatus(@Param ("status") String status);
}
```

**Service**

```
package com.example.proyectoInventario.service;

import com.example.proyectoInventario.domain.Orders;
import java.util.List;

public interface OrdersService {
    
    public List<Orders> findByStatus(String status);
    
}
```

**Service Implementation**

```
package com.example.proyectoInventario.service;

import com.example.proyectoInventario.dao.OrdersDAO;
import com.example.proyectoInventario.domain.Orders;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
public class OrdersServiceImpl implements OrdersService{
    @Autowired
    private OrdersDAO ordersDAO;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public List<Orders> findByStatus(String status) {
        return ordersDAO.findByStatus(status);
    }
```

**Controller** (I think here could be something wrong in addition)

```
package com.example.proyectoInventario.web;

import com.example.proyectoInventario.domain.Orders;
import com.example.proyectoInventario.service.OrdersService;
import java.util.List;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
@Slf4j
public class IndexController {

    String url = "";

    @Autowired
    private OrdersService ordersService;
    
     @GetMapping("/{status}")
    public List<Orders> listarOrdenesporStatus(@RequestParam String status){
        return ordersService.findByStatus(status);
    }
```

**Project Application**

```
package com.example.proyectoInventario;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.example.proyectoInventario")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.example.proyectoInventario.dao")
@EntityScan(basePackages="com.example.proyectoInventario.domain")
public class ProyectoInventarioApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProyectoInventarioApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**Application.properties**

```
server.port= 8000
spring.main.banner-mode=off

# Base de datos
spring.jpa.database=MySQL
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/inventory?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=

#This line it was added by suggestions of Netbeans itself
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the problem. To solution this, I replaced correctly the imported libraries for @Table Annotation.

Initially, i used this Spring import:

```
import org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table;
```

The correct library:

```
import javax.persistence.Table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is wrong, change orders to Orders( Entity class name)

Try this

Query("SELECT o FROM Orders o WHERE o.status= :status")

Comment: I've change these lines like you suggested but it still not working. Thanks!
```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(value="Orders")
public class Orders implements Serializable {
//...
}
```

```
@Query("SELECT o FROM Orders o WHERE o.status= :status")
```

Comment: @Table(value="Orders") let this will be same as before and share the error.

Comment: I updated the table annotation like you suggested:
```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(value="Orders")
``` 
and the query now:
```
Query("SELECT o FROM Orders o WHERE o.status= :status")
```
but it's still not working. 
I will update the error trace in the main post. Thx!